# Error Page Exception

Tags: java, security, spring-mvc

When I tried to update a name field in my application , I have received error page with this error -

> SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your
>   application to handle the Original Exception printed below.

```
Original Exception: 
Error Message: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /custnull
Error Code: 404
Target Servlet: customerEstablishment
Error Stack: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /custnull 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor._processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:948) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:929) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:483) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet_aroundBody0(FrameworkServlet.java:827) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet$AjcClosure1.run(FrameworkServlet.java:1) 
at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) 
at au.com.westpac.jcx.sparrow.aspects.performance.HttpServletCorrelation.aroundHttpServletInvocation(HttpServletCorrelation.java:36) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) 
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307) 
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562) 
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255) 
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97) 
at au.com.wbg.filter.QSParamsFilter.doFilter(QSParamsFilter.java:70) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
at au.com.wbg.filter.BranchFilter.doFilter(BranchFilter.java:155) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
at au.com.wbg.filter.ResourceAccessFilter.doFilter(ResourceAccessFilter.java:69) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
at au.com.wbg.filter.CSRFWebFilter.doFilter(CSRFWebFilter.java:113) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
at au.com.wbg.filter.LogbackFilter.doFilter(LogbackFilter.java:81) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
at au.com.wbg.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:85) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
at au.com.wbg.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:60) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200) 
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459) 
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526) 
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312) 
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88) 
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784) 
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) 
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862) 
Error Page Exception: 
Error Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
Error Code: 0
Target Servlet: 
Error Stack: 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at au.com.wbg.service.user.UserRoleDivTag.writeTagContent(UserRoleDivTag.java:108) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80) 
at _ibmjsp.WEB_2D_INF.jsp._404error._jspx_meth_role_ruleDiv_0(_404error.java:168) 
at _ibmjsp.WEB_2D_INF.jsp._404error._jspService(_404error.java:125) 
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) 
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307) 
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562) 
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255) 
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) 
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122) 
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3328) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1095) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200) 
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459) 
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526) 
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312) 
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88) 
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784) 
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) 
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Comment: post your code snippet.

Comment: Your problem lies here: au.com.wbg.service.user.UserRoleDivTag.writeTagContent(UserRoleDivTag.java:108)

Comment: can you breif me about what exactly had faced issue with

Comment: how you have configured `/custnull` in web.xml

Comment: i have configured it as <url-pattern>/cust/*</url-pattern> in web.xml

Comment: as per stack trace `Error Message: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /custnull`